# CORS - API Authentication : Sessions (CSRF Security) - Work Around?

Tags: php, api, session

I am currently using the CORS method (ReWriting my external requests from `example.com/api?param=args` to `example.com/api/public/api.php?param=args`) and sending the get Request like so:

```
$.get('http://www.example.com/api'), { param: "args" })
    .done(function (data) {
        alert(data);
    });
```

This works absolutely fine and I can now Cross-Domain reference with Requests and responses to my API software.

I am now wondering, I set up a test request to try achieve a `Session`.

```
session_start();
if(isset($_GET['store'])):
    $_SESSION['key'] = $_GET['store'];
elseif(isset($_GET['show'])):
    echo $_SESSION['key'];
endif;
```

When I go to the link directly in my browser, this works fine however, when I send a request from the external domain, the second request seems to "forget" the `Session key` I stored.

Code:

```
$.get('http://www.example.com/api'), { store: "test" })
    .done(function () {
        $.get('http://www.example.com/api'), { show: "args" })
            .done(function (data) {
               alert(data);
        })
    });
```

> Data is undefined

Is there a way I can make the server that is sending the requests actually "save" or "remember" the session on the API server or is there a way I can achieve this by using a work around?

Note that the API will be used by multiple people - like a plugin - and each `key` will be actually added once they send a `Register` param as a request with the admin details of there account so I need some sort of authentication to using the API and cannot actually think of a way around not using Session's or getting it to work using session's.

Please note also, if I am using session (as you can see like that), it creates a `CRSF attack`. Is there a work around this also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, credentials (such as cookies) are not sent on cross-origin requests because they [trigger preflight requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests).

The [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) describes how to enable credentials:

```
$.ajax({
   url: a_cross_domain_url,
   xhrFields: {
      withCredentials: true
   }
});
```

> cannot actually think of a way around not using Session's

Pass an auth token back in the body of the response. Read it with JS. Have the JS include it in each request.

> Please note also, if I am using session (as you can see like that), it creates a CRSF attack. Is there a work around this also?

Don't use the `*` origin in your Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. Only allow trusted sites to use your API.

Comment: I am not actually sending the cookies in the request, I am sending the data in a Param which then the API will store a session for that request to that server. If I try this in the browser - it works fine, however, the second request I send seems to actually "forget" the `SESSION`. But that last part about the CRSF attack, that's awesome! I can work this

Comment: `Have the JS include it in each request.` <-- perfect, thanks so much!

Comment: @KyleE4K — "I am not actually sending the cookies in the request" — Umm, how do you think sessions work?

Comment: The API is doing: `session_start();`, the request is just a string lol

Comment: @KyleE4K — You might want to investigate what `session_start` does before you laugh at people. It reads the cookies sent by the client to look for a session token and then either gets the data from the matching session in the server's session store or creates a new session in that store and adds a Set-Cookie header to the response to tell the client about it. The client then includes that cookie in subsequent responses so that the server and associate the session data with the right browser.

Comment: well, i did it your Ajax way and it don't even work in browser anymore so I just restructed it so that you have to send your key everytime x) thanks tho